# Numpy array, indexing and convolving confusion

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to complete the following function, but I have been running into problems with the indexing, resulting in "ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (0,9) (5)".

I think my error might be coming from how I'm trying to call the values from ssd_difference[], but I'm not entirely sure.

Also how would I go about using convolve2d based on the hint given below? I understand numpy has a function for it, but I have no idea what I would need to put in to make it work.

Additional information: binomialFilter5() returns a 5x1 numpy array of dtype float representing a binomial filter. I'm also assuming that the "weights[]" are the ssd_difference[] values.

```
def transitionDifference(ssd_difference):
```

""" Compute the transition costs between frames, taking dynamics into
        account.

Instructions:
        1. Iterate through the rows and columns of ssd difference, ignoring the
           first two values and the last two values.
            1a. For each value at i, j, multiply the binomial filter of length
                five (implemented later in the code) by the weights starting two 
                frames before until two frames after, and take the sum of those 
                products.

```
            i.e. Your weights for frame i are:
                 [weight[i - 2, j - 2],
                  weight[i - 1, j - 1],
                  weight[i, j],
                  weight[i + 1, j + 1],
                  weight[i + 2, j + 2]]
```

Multiply that by the binomial filter weights at each i, j to get
                your output.

It may take a little bit of understanding to get why we are
                computing this, the simple explanation is that to change from
                frame 4 to 5, lets call this ch(4, 5), and we make this weight:

ch(4, 5) = ch(2, 3) + ch(3, 4) + ch(4, 5) + ch(5, 6) + ch(6, 7)

This accounts for the weights in previous changes and future
                changes when considering the current frame.

Of course, we weigh all these sums by the binomial filter, so
                that the weight ch(4, 5) is still the most important one, but
                hopefully that gives you a better understanding.

```
Args:
    ssd_difference (numpy.ndarray): A difference matrix as produced by your
                                    ssd function.

Returns:
    output (numpy.ndarray): A difference matrix that takes preceding and
                            following frames into account. The output
                            difference matrix should have the same dtype as
                            the input, but be 4 rows and columns smaller,
                            corresponding to only the frames that have valid
                            dynamics.

Hint: There is an efficient way to do this with 2d convolution. Think about
      the coordinates you are using as you consider the preceding and
      following frame pairings.
"""

output = np.zeros((ssd_difference.shape[0] - 4,
                   ssd_difference.shape[1] - 4), dtype=ssd_difference.dtype)
# WRITE YOUR CODE HERE.
for i in range(len(ssd_difference)):
    for j in range(len(ssd_difference)):
        if i == 0:
            if j > 1:
                output[i,j] = np.sum( ssd_difference[i-2:i+2]*binomialFilter5())
        elif i == ssd_difference.shape[0] - 1:
            if j < ssd_difference.shape[1] - 2:
                output[i,j] = np.sum( ssd_difference[i-2:i+2]*binomialFilter5())
        else:
            output[i,j] = np.sum( ssd_difference[i-2:i+2]*binomialFilter5())
# END OF FUNCTION.
return output
```

Comment: Show us more of the `ValueError`, specifically the line(s) marked with `---->`.  Focus on the operands that have `shapes (0,9) (5)`, and what is the `operation` that is trying to combine them.

Comment: Sorry, the line was  output[i,j] = np.sum( ssd_difference[i-2:i+2]*binomialFilter5())

  I understand that I can't multiply together a matrix of differing sizes, but I can't think of any other way to accomplish the function's purpose (at least according to the instructions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented, you really should tell us the line that produced the error message.

But I can guess, since there are just a couple of lines that do an operation that involves broadcasting.  Most likely it is:

```
output[i,j] = np.sum( ssd_difference[i-2:i+2]*binomialFilter5())
```

You write that `binomialFilter5()` produces a `(5,1)` array, but the error talks about a `(5,)`.  It probably doesn't matter here, but you really should keep the number of dimensions straight.  Sometimes `(5,1)` is signficantly different from `(5,)`.

`output` has shape `(ssd_difference.shape[0] - 4, ssd_difference.shape[1] - 4)`.  But you are iterating `i,j` both over `range(len(ssd_difference))`.  `output[i,j]` will eventually result in an `index error`.  Especially when iterating over a 2d array, it is better to use the correct `shape` element, rather than `len()`.

But I suspect the immediate error results from `ssd_difference[i-2:i+2]`.  When `i==0`, this is `ssd_difference[-2:2]`.  This is producing the `(0,9)` array, since the `-2` index means second from the last, which is larger than `2`.

I think you are intending to pull 5 rows from this array, to match the 5 values in the other array.  A correct iteration, would I think be:

```
for i in range(output.shape[0]):
    for j in range(output.shape[1]):
       ....
       output[i,j] = np.sum(ssd_difference[i:i+5, :] * binomialFilter5())
       ...
```

You should test expressions like that individually in an interactive shell, with selected values of `i`.  `ssd_difference[i:i+5, :]` should have shape `(5,9)`, and `binomialFilter5()` should be `(5,1)`.

Comment: This makes sense, thank you so much! Sorry about not including the line that the error was pointing to. Still trying to learn proper code/stackoverflow etiquette.

Comment: Just an update to anyone who might be having similar issues. Numpy.transpose() is your friend.